# Highmaps: how to disable map zoom by mouse scroll

Tags: highcharts

I am able to display a map on a page. However, when I scroll up or down the page with the mouse middle scroll button (Logitech mouse), the map zooms in and out. I hope to disable it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's option for that, see [`mapNavigation.enableMouseWheelZoom`](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/mapNavigation.enableMouseWheelZoom).

Comment: URL update: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/mapNavigation.enableMouseWheelZoom